# Select data with a dynamic where clause on non-indexed column

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 30 columns and millions of entries.
I want to execute a stored procedure on this table to search data.
The search criteria are passed in a parameter to this SP.
If I serach data with a dynamic WHERE clause on non-indexed column, it spends a lot of time.

Below is an example :

```
Select counterparty_name from counterparty where  counterparty_name = 'test'
```

In this example this counterparty is in th row number 5000000.

As explained,I can't create an index to this table .

I would like to know if the processing time is normal.

I would like to know if there is any recommandation that can improve the execution time?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an index on the column then it will have to do a scan of the clustered index in order to look for the data (or maybe a smaller index which might have that column included in it). As such it is going to take a long time.